# Rails oracle raw16

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

I'm using Rails 3.2.1 and I have stuck on some problem for quite long.

I'm using oracle enhanced adapter and I have raw(16) (uuid) column and when I'm trying to display the data there is 2 situations:

1) I see the weird symbols

2) I'm getting incompatible character encoding:  Ascii-8bit and utf-8.

In my application.rb file I added the
config.encoding = 'utf-8'
and in my view file I added
'#encoding=utf-8'
But so far nothing worked

I also tried to add html_safe but it failed  .

How can I safely diaply my uuid data?

Thank you very much

Answer:
I used the unpack method to convert the 
binary  with those parameters
H8H4H4H4H12 and in the end joined the
array :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `RAW` datatype is a string of bytes that can take any value. This includes binary data that doesn't translate to anything meaningful in ASCII or UTF-8 or in any character set.

You should really read [Joel Spolsky's note about character sets and unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) before continuing.

Now, since the data can't be translated reliably to a string, how can we display it? Usually we [convert or encode it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding), for instance:

- we could use the hexadecimal representation where each byte is converted to two `[0-9A-F]` characters (in Oracle using the [`RAWTOHEX`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions143.htm#i78517) function). This is fine for display of small binary field such as `RAW(16)`.
- you can also use other encodings such as [base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), in Oracle with the [`UTL_ENCODE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_encode.htm#CACECFHF) package.

Comment: How can I add function in my model? I only specified the name of the column,  can I also run function itself